Windows 11で起動時のフォーム位置をデフォルト動作(前回閉じた位置に表示)する方法
Visual Studioで「Windows フォームアプリケーション(.NET Framework)」(C#)を作成しましたが、フォームの起動位置がWindowsのデフォルト動作(前回閉じた位置に表示する)になりません(空のプロジェクトを作って試しても同じ結果になりました)。
フォームのプロパティStartPositionをManualにするとLocationで指定した位置、CenterScreenだと画面の真ん中、WindowsDefaultLocationだと(Windows標準の動作ではなく)毎回ランダムな位置になります。
詳細な環境は以下の通りです。
Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.10.0
.NET Framework 4.8
Windows 11 Pro 23H2 64bit

この辺の記事がWindows11でも参考になりそうです。閉じたときのフォームの位置を記憶する 本当に鳩でも分かるC#講座, 【ワレコのC#】Formアプリ 前回終了時 ウインドウ位置・サイズを記憶復元, C# WinUI 3 アンパッケージ化したアプリで前回終了時の位置にフォームを復帰する方法（改良版）

「Windowsデフォルトの動作」をさせるだけでも結構手間がかかるみたいですね……。Visual Studioで作ったアプリがそうなってしまうのが謎ですが……。

誤解から始まっているようですが、「前回の位置と同じ位置で表示」は、Windowsの世界においてデフォルトではありません。デフォルトは古くからの仕様で左上から徐々に右下にずれていくという挙動になっています。このため、前回と同じ位置を仕様とするなら自分で作り込む必要があります。ただ、前回と同じ位置が環境の都合で画面外となるケースもあるので、他の人にも配る予定があれば注意が必要です。

kunifさんがコメントされた記事を読みましたがいずれも不十分です。実際に試すとわかりますが、アプリケーションを最大化したまま終了すると、

最大化したサイズを保存するだけなので、次回起動時は大きさは最大となるものの、通常ウィンドウとして起動してしまう
最大化していないので、最大化前の元の位置・サイズに戻せない

という欠点があります。もちろん、Localtionプロパティ・Sizeプロパティは最大値時の位置・サイズを指しているので、元の位置・サイズを読み出すこともできません。
結局、WinFormsでは解決できません。

ではどうするかというと、

必要なタイミングで、GetWindowPlacement関数で情報を取得し、保存しておき、
OnLoadイベント時辺りで、SetWindowPlacement関数で復元する。

が妥当な線かなと思います。

フォーム終了時に Window の状態、座標、サイズを保存し、フォーム起動時に、それらを復元することで実現できます。
アプリケーション設定で、これらの値を保存するすためのプロパティを作成しておきます。

対象のフォームに FormClosing イベントを追加し、フォーム終了時に Window の状態、座標、サイズをアプリケーション設定に保存します。
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
    {
        // 座標
        settings.Form1WindowPosition = this.Location;
        // サイズ
        settings.Form1WindowSize = this.Size;
    }
    else
    {
        // 通常時の座標
        settings.Form1WindowPosition = this.RestoreBounds.Location;
        // 通常時のサイズ
        settings.Form1WindowSize = this.RestoreBounds.Size; 
    }

    // Windows の状態
    settings.Form1WindowState = this.WindowState;
    // 各設定を保存
    settings.Save(); 
}

対象のフォームに Load イベントを追加し、フォーム起動時に、アプリケーション設定から Window の状態、座標、サイズを復元します。
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

    if (settings.Form1WindowSize.Width == 0 && settings.Form1WindowSize.Height == 0)
    {
        // 初回起動時は、何もしない。
        return;
    }
    
    // 座標の復元
    this.Location = settings.Form1WindowPosition;
    // サイズの復元
    this.Size = settings.Form1WindowSize;

    // Windows 状態の復元 - 最小化の場合は、通常として復元する
    this.WindowState = settings.Form1WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized ? FormWindowState.Normal : settings.Form1WindowState;
}

Window 状態が、通常、最大化の場合は、それらの状態で復元。最小化状態で閉じられた場合は、通常状態で復元するようにしています。
また、最大化状態で起動し、その後、ユーザー操作によって通常状態に戻した場合にも、以前通常状態であった位置やサイズも復元されます。
